# Firebase cloud functions Appcheck for https.onRequest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

As per documentation we can add appcheck as below,

```html
exports.yourCallableFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // context.app will be undefined if the request doesn't include a valid
  // App Check token.
  if (context.app == undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.')
  }
});
```

My question right now is how do I need to add app-check for below scenario?

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

});
```

Answer (score 7):

In the client, get an appCheck token from Firebase. Send it in a header to your function. Get the token from the req object's headers. Verify the the token with firebase-admin. I'll include the documentation for the client below, then the gist of how I implemented it client side with Apollo-client graphql. Then I'll include the documentation for the backend, then the gist of how I implemented the backend, again with Apollo.

client (from the documentation):

```
const { initializeAppCheck, getToken } = require('firebase/app-check');

const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(
    app,
    { provider: provider } // ReCaptchaV3Provider or CustomProvider
);

const callApiWithAppCheckExample = async () => {
  let appCheckTokenResponse;
  try {
      appCheckTokenResponse = await getToken(appCheck, /* forceRefresh= */ false);
  } catch (err) {
      // Handle any errors if the token was not retrieved.
      return;
  }

  // Include the App Check token with requests to your server.
  const apiResponse = await fetch('https://yourbackend.example.com/yourApiEndpoint', {
      headers: {
          'X-Firebase-AppCheck': appCheckTokenResponse.token,
      }
  });

  // Handle response from your backend.
};
```

client (gist from my implementation)

```
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { app } from '../firebase/setup';
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider, getToken } from "firebase/app-check"

let appCheck
let appCheckTokenResponse

const getAppCheckToken = async () => {
  const appCheckTokenResponsePromise = await getToken(appCheck, /* forceRefresh= */ false)
  appCheckTokenResponse = appCheckTokenResponsePromise
}

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV === 'production') {
    appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('my_public_key_from_recaptcha_V3'),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
    })
    await getAppCheckToken()
  }

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      'X-Firebase-AppCheck': appCheckTokenResponse?.token,
    },
  }
})
```

backend / server (from the documentation)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebaseApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();

const appCheckVerification = async (req, res, next) => {
    const appCheckToken = req.header('X-Firebase-AppCheck');

    if (!appCheckToken) {
        res.status(401);
        return next('Unauthorized');
    }

    try {
        const appCheckClaims = await firebaseAdmin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);

        // If verifyToken() succeeds, continue with the next middleware
        // function in the stack.
        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401);
        return next('Unauthorized');
    }
}

app.get('/yourApiEndpoint', [appCheckVerification], (req, res) => {
    // Handle request.
});
```

backend / server (gist from my implementation)

```
import { https } from 'firebase-functions'
import gqlServer from './graphql/server'
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const env = process.env.ENV || functions.config().config.env

const server = gqlServer()

const api = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    server(req, res)
})

export { api }

. . .


import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const env = process.env.ENV || functions.config().config.env

admin.initializeApp()


appCheckVerification = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const appCheckToken = req.header('X-Firebase-AppCheck')
  if (!appCheckToken) {
    return false
  }

  try {
    const appCheckClaims = await admin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return false
  }
 }

. . .


const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  introspection: isDevelopment,
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req, res }) => {
            
    if (!isDevelopment && !isTest) {
      const appCheckVerification = await appCheckVerification(req, res)
        if (!appCheckVerification) throw Error('Something went wrong with verification')
 }
return { req, res, }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [enforce app check in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) it will only allow calls from apps that are registered in your project.

I'm not sure if that is sufficient for your use-case though, as I doubt most apps where you can provide a web hook will have implemented app attestation - which is how App Check recognizes valid requests.

Comment: Does denied calls also cost ??

Comment: @Noobdeveloper SURE, google is NEVER going to let you run out of charge... the only advantage of this it will help you to avoid a long complex database query or something like that, but the function call, memory and data transfer costs STILL APPLY

Comment: Don't you need to add the app check token in some header on the client ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an app check token in the client and verify the token in the server using firebase admin SDK. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/custom-resource) is the firebase documentation for the same

Comment: Could you provide an example from the documentation? This will help future users if the URL becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase enable App check enforcement documentation teaches you that to validate the caller from your function you just need to check the context.app then gives you an example like this

```
exports.EXAMPLE = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions?authuser=0

But when you are deploying your function in the google cloud dashboard, you select HTTP FUNCTION -> nodejs 14 -> then you are directed to code like this

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

My question when I saw this was: "How am i going to get a context if I only have request/response"

The answer is simple. **YOU MUST SWITCH THE CONSTRUCTORS**

You must re-write your function in a way that instead of dealing with req/res like any express function you are dealing with context/data

http functions are different of callable functions (the ones that deals with context/data)

IT IS SIMILAR BUT NOT EXACTLY EQUAL AND SOME MODIFICATIONS WILL BE NECESSARY.

mainly if your function deals with async stuff and have a delayed response you are going to need to rewrite many stuff

check this tutorial
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 0):

**Client**

1. After deploying the function, set the function-URL in the client.
2. Set the AppCheck token in the client.

Examples can be found in the docs, here is the one for [Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/custom-resource):

```dart
final appCheckToken = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken();

if (appCheckToken != null) {
  final response = await http.get(

    Uri.parse("https://yourbackend.example.com/yourExampleEndpoint"),
    headers: {"X-Firebase-AppCheck": appCheckToken},

   );
} else {
  // Error: couldn't get an App Check token.
}
```

**Server**

When deploying the function, the console will print the resulting function-URL. Use this URL in the client's code.

1. Set Cors to enable all incoming calls (depends on your project).
2. Verify the incoming AppCheck-Token.
3. Depending on verification result, return 401 or process the request normally.

```js
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});

exports.createBundle = functions.region("europe-west3")
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
      cors(request, response, async () => {
        const appCheckToken = request.header("X-Firebase-AppCheck");
        if (!appCheckToken) {
          response.statusMessage = "Unauthorized";
          response.statusCode = 401;
          response.end();
        }

        try {
          await admin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
        } catch (err) {
          response.statusMessage = "Unauthorized";
          response.statusCode = 401;
          response.end();
        }

        const payload = "your response payload";

        // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache
        response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400");
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.end(payload);
      });
    });
```